# Random number generators in R such as rnorm giving identical output on repeated runs

Tags: r, random, save

I have a script that loads an RData file.  This RData file was generated by a different script using the save.image function.  When I run the script that loads the RData file, rnorm gives me identical output on every run.

Here is a simple example.

Script to generate RData file,

```
rm(list = ls())
save.image('test.RData')
```

Script that loads RData and calls rnorm,

```
rm(list = ls())
load('test.RData')
input = rnorm(10)
print(input)
```

I have found one way round this is to use save rather than save.image in the first script.  However this is not very convenient because I do not always know in advance which objects from my environment I want to keep.  But I would definitely like rnorm to use a different seed each time I run the second script.

Answer (score 3):

The probably easiest way to do this is to reinitialize the seed (which is stored in the image and therefore restored when you load it):

```
set.seed(NULL)
```

before calling rnorm. So your code would have to be changed to

```
rm(list = ls())
load('test.RData')
set.seed(NULL)
input = rnorm(10)
print(input)
```

**Edit:** A different option is to modify the script generating the RData file by adding `rm(.Random.seed)` immediatly before the `save.image()` call. This ensures that, whenever the image is loaded, the seed of the PRNG (pseudo random number generator) is not modified. Thus the script loading the image does not need to do anything special to use a different sequence of pseudo random numbers on each execution. Which of the two solutions is more appropriate for you probably depends on your specific use case.

Comment: The recommended way of reinitializing the seed is `set.seed(NULL)`; see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! - Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  That answers my question.

Comment: Great - If you feel my answer has solved your issue, please accept it.